# Run multiple IPython magic command at the same line

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to use multiple magic commands on an expression?
For example, I want to measure ram usage and execution time of a certain function where I'm gonna use memory_profiler for measuring the ram usage.

```py
!pip install memory_profiler
%load_ext memory_profiler
```

Below's code is working fine, but it would run the function twice.

```py
%memit function()
%time function()
```

Is it possible to use multiple magic function ? Maybe something like this

```py
%memit %time function() # This will give syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap the two:

```
%time %memit function()
```

Comment: Although this technically works I don't think it is a good solution - the timing will now include the time it takes to do the memory profiling, and not only how long it takes to run the function.

Comment: Can you explain why swapping the magic command would make it work?